# Aplicar una clase cuando un 'hijo' tenga activo

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda que me esta volviendo loco. Navegue por todos lados y recurro a ustedes.

Necesito que "Next" desaparezca (`opacity:0`) cuando el primer `.rojo` "`.rojo:first-child`" tenga `.active`. Y que `Prev` desaparezca pero cuando "`.rojo:last-child`" tenga el `.active`

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">slide 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">slide 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">slide 3</div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">Prev</a>

<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">Next</a>
```

en `CSS` uso selectores, pero obviamente no me funcionar porque `.rojo` y `.link` no son correlativos. `.rojo` es hijo de `.pepe`

Nota: Es un `slider`. `Next` y `Prev` vendrían a ser las flechas y quiero que en el primer `slide` activo (`.rojo.active`) la flecha previa no se vea, porque no se puede ir para atrás.

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Abrazo a la comunidad.

Comment: Puedes usar javascript? jquery?

Comment: Hola @JCAguilera. Si puedo, pero no se armarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Usando [jquery](https://jquery.com/) resulta muy fácil:

```
function hideButtons() {
    $('.link').show();
    $('.link-2').show();
    if ($('.rojo').first().hasClass('active')) {
        $('.link-2').hide();
    }
    if ($('.rojo').last().hasClass('active')) {
        $('.link').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    hideButtons();
    $('.link').click(() => {
        hideButtons();
    })
    $('.link-2').click(() => {
        hideButtons();
    })
})
```

Primero fíjate en la función `hideButtons()`. Aquí primero "mostramos" los dos botones (por si están escondidos) y también tenemos dos `if`: uno que verifica si el primer elemento tiene la clase `active`, y el otro verifica si el último elemento tiene la clase `active`. Luego oculta o muestra los enlaces `Next` o `Prev` según corresponda.

Ahora fíjate en la segunda parte, jquery funciona con eventos, así que asigné un evento click a los enlaces con clase `link` y `link-2` para que al hacer click en ellos verifique con la función `hideButtons()` si es necesario esconder o no algúno de esos dos enlaces.
También añadí `hideButtons()` dentro de `$(document).ready()` para que también se verifique al inicio, cuando el sitio cargue.

Comment: Si no sabes usar jquery puedes ver [esta guía](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/pasos-para-ejecutar-jquery.html)

Comment: Gracias @JCAguilera. Efectivamente la flecha desaparecio, pero al avanzar con los Slide no vuelve a aparecer. Es un carousel de 3 slide. La flecha PREV (ojo que modifique los nombres del POSTEO para que se entienda mas), desaparece de todos los slide. La idea es que cuando queda activo el segundo, aparezca.
Y despues el mismo JS, pero que en el 'last-child' desaparezca "link-2".

Comment: Hola, recuerda publicar toda la información necesaria para que así podamos responder tu pregunta de la mejor manera. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa, pense que habia quedado claro. Muchas gracias por la información. Aun asi no funciona. En el slide 1, el primero boton desaparece. Pero cuando presiono NEXT y se activa el 2 slide, el boton de PREV no vuelve a aparecer. Es como que se oculta en todo el carousel, no solamente en el primer slide.
Con el boton NEXT, cuando llego al ultimo slide no desaparece, tengo que darle CLIC y ahi si lo hace. Pero la idea es que cuando detecta el ultimo .rojo con active, desaparezca automatico.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, disculpa por la tardanza. Ahora creo que debiese funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por respondrme @JCAguilera. Aun sigue sin funcionar, pero no se si es por un error en las clases. En realidad por confusión.
Asi que lo que hice fue actualizar el codigo de mi Carousel, pero con las clases reales y ya no con un ejemplo como '.rojo' etc.
El codigo que pongo arriba es tan cual como es el Carousel. 
Lo que me recomendaste sigue haciendo lo mismo, que en el Slide 1, la flecha PREV no aparece, pero al avanzar a la 2da, no aparece. Y en la ultima, la flecha de NEXT no desaparece, salvo que le haga clic (pero la idea es que desaparezca automaticamente.).